# WebKit equivalent to Firefox's "moz-chunked-arraybuffer" xhr responseType

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, web-audio-api

I would like to read an MP3 stream (from icecast, to read ICY metadata an then pass the binary MP3 data to a Web Audio Api).

Firefox has a "moz-chunked-arraybuffer" xhr responseType to read data on progress, but I can't find any equivalent for webkit / chrome.

---

EDIT 2014/02/03 :

Chrome has started implementing xhr.responseType "stream"

The "parsing" is landed in Chrome (with the --enable-experimental-webkit-features flag) but the xhr.response resulted object (Stream) is not yet useable directly in Javascript : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240603

---

EDIT 2014/07/10 :

The spec is now developped : https://github.com/whatwg/streams

Chromium devs plans to "do some prototype without waiting for completion of standardization"

---

EDIT 2015/01/22 :

The [Streams API](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/) will not be implemented in XHR (it was just for prototyping). [It will finally be implemented](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/533) in the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) implementation, which was recently shipped in Chrome (behind the experimental flag).

---

EDIT 2015/01/30 : 
Fetch API has an [Intent to Ship](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/qwRO52vsQlU/CPLC4G6oG9IJ) !
Streams API are announced as "upcoming integrations", it's quite here !

---

EDIT 2015/04/15 :

\o/ Glory !
The Fetch API is now landed in Chrome 42 (current stable release : http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.fr/2015/04/stable-channel-update_14.html).
42 is not only the answer to life, the universe and everything but also to this question "How can I consume an "AJAX request" like a stream" :

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/fetch-api/fetch-response-stream.html

End of the story :)

Comment: Thanks for the updates! They are much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, streaming with the Fetch API is **still not** enabled by default in Firefox, so we still have to rely on "moz-chunked-arraybuffer" to support Firefox :(

Comment: Short example of using Fetch API and ReadableStream to display MJPEG video stream: https://github.com/proxy-m/mjpeg-stream-player

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that WebKit will get https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/streams-api/raw-file/tip/Overview.htm instead

Comment: Has any vendor at all implemented this yet?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but to my knowledge there's not currently a webkit equivalent. Originally the chunked-arraybuffer response type arose from a concern similar to yours:

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JulSep/0924.html

Additionally, MDN lists the responseType as only available in Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your issue is not having seen the full AudioContext object for html5.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

You can decode audio data : decodeAudioData()
You can play music via an AudioBuffer that can stream music to you via a web socket or just chunked http streaming.

When you want to play a song you just call the playSound()

So the real answer is use the AudioContext and you'll be golden

Comment: It _COULD_ be. I was almost there ...
1) You need to remove the extra bytes from Icecast (icy-metadata)
2) decodeAudioData() adds some extra miliseconds of "blank" audio in each buffer which results in a bad quality for the audio