# Accessing already downloaded data

Tags: javascript, html

I need to download a large (>100MB) file of data via `XmlHttpRequest`. The data is from a third party and I would like to display the content gradually as it gets downloaded.

So I thought the following would work:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open( "GET", mirror.url, true );
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

req.onload = function( oEvent ) {
    console.log( "DONE" );
};
var current_offset = 0;
req.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
    if( event.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
    }
    var data = req.response;
    // Fails here: req.response is null till load is called

    var dataView = new DataView( data );
    while( current_offset < dataView.byteLength ) {
        // do work
        ++current_offset;
    }

    console.log( "OFFSET " + current_offset + " [" + percentComplete + "%]" );

}, false);
try {
    req.send( null );
} catch( er ) {
    console.log( er );
}
```

Sadly, according to the spec, `.response` is not available.

Is there any way to access the already downloaded data without going to such horrible workarounds like using `Flash`?

EDIT:

Found at least a working non-standard solution for Firefox:

```
responseType = "moz-chunked-arraybuffer";
```

See also: [WebKit equivalent to Firefox's "moz-chunked-arraybuffer" xhr responseType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185499/webkit-equivalent-to-firefoxs-moz-chunked-arraybuffer-xhr-responsetype)

Comment: Wait, you want to send 100MB to my browser?! Which might be on my phone?

Comment: @DOK I trust you are intelligent enough to not call a bandwidth and computation intensitive website on our phone.

Comment: Have you tried using req.responseText instead?

Comment: @JamieJag No, I need binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to download only parts of the file using range requests to only download parts of the file. For more information see the following blog post [HTTP Status: 206 Partial Content and Range Requests](http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/).

If you have control over the server you could also split up the file on the server side and download chunks of it. This way you would be able to access the response as the different chunks are recieved.

A third approach would be to use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to download the data.

If you have no control of the server you are downloading from and none of the other options will work, you will probably need to implement a proxy service that will act as an intermediate and allow you to download only part of it.

Comment: Sadly the data is from a third party, so I have to use the file the way they provide it.

Comment: Added two more possible solutions that might work when you don't have control of the server.

Comment: As long as _Chrome_ doesn't implement _Streams API_, this really seems to be the only solution. Will have to look at a partial content workaround, since I don't want to have costs for hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a library for this?

I've never used it to load a 100MB file, but [PreloadJS](http://createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS) is pretty nice for loading all kinds of assets.

Comment: Is there any mention, that you can access the partially downloaded state? Cannot find it.

Comment: Hmm. I thought I remembered that you could, but perhaps you're right. It might not be possible until the data finishes loading. You can get to the XHR.response, and it is an ArrayBuffer object, but it might only be populated after load.